# How to connect/run map reduce on Hadoop installed on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I have successfully installed Hadoop on Ubutu and running well, now I want to run a sample mapReduce using Eclipse connecting the Hadoop I installed.

it is really great if some could helps to sort this.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You can just export the eclipse MR code as Jar and place it in the Local file system and run the following command.

```
hadoop jar <jarFileName> [<argumentsToBePassed>]
```